# $(∀x)(∃y)(x>y)$ is false. But then why is $ (∀x)(∃y)(x\geq y)$ true?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, predicate-logic

Given the Universe is the set of natural numbers, then $(∀x)(∃y)(x>y)$ is false. But then why is $(∀x)(∃y)(x\geq y)$ true?

The first equation and the second equation is the same except for "=" in the second equation.
so i don't get how that affects the statement to this degree.
Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you look at $y = x$?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: @Kris, the universe if natural numbers.

Comment: @DanielFischer Assuming $=$ is reflexive.

Comment: Note that $(∀x)(∃y)(x = y)$ is always true, whatever the universe is; the second statement is weaker (i.e., claims less) than this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the smallest number in the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ (since you mention that the universe is the set of all natural numbers): the smallest number in $\mathbb N$ would be $0$ or $1$, depending on your definition.  Let's just go with $0$.

Since $0 \in \mathbb N$, the universally quantified "x" means the inequality must hold for **every** natural number $x$, *including* $x = 0.\;$ Now, does there exist ***any*** $y \in \mathbb N$ such that that $0 > y\;$?

On the other hand, if we allow *equality* too, then we have that it is *true* that there exists a $\,y \in \mathbb N\,$ such that $\;0 \geq y,\,$ namely, $\,y = 0:$ That is, it is certainly true that $\;0 \geq 0.$

The same logic applies if $x = 1$ instead of $x = 0$, if you are working with a definition of the natural numbers $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. On similar note, how does (∀y)(∃x)(x>y) = true? Since the question is within the universe of natural numbers, shouldn't "All y" cover all the natural numbers, and there can't exist any x such that x > y? Thanks!

Comment: The naturals have no upperbound: there is no "greatest element" that we can call $x$ to make it untrue. That is, whatever y we choose, we can find an $x \gt y$: simply let $x = y+1$...then whatever $y$ we pick, there exists an $x = y + 1$ so that $y+1 \gt y$ and so the proposition is always true.

Comment: @user1486802 I recommend sounding them out in your head.  What you're thinking of is more akin to $\exists x \forall y (x\gt y)$; that is, 'there exists an $x$ such that for all $y$, $x$ is greater than $y$' - in other words, 'there exists a number greater than all numbers'.  By contrast, $\forall y\exists x (x\gt y)$ is 'for every $y$, there exists an $x$ such that $x$ is greater than $y$'; 'for each number, there's some bigger number'.  (Or, by the contrapositive, 'no number is the biggest'). Using this formulation, it should be clear why it's true- for each number, we can find a bigger one.

Comment: @amWhy, thanks! i got it.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Any ordered set with a minimum element provides an example where the first is false and the second is true, because there can be nothing below the minimum element.

Answer (score 2):

Another take on this question is to try and write the latter in terms of the former:
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: x \geq y \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"write $\;\geq\;$ in terms of $\;>\;$ -- since know something about that already"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: x > y \:\lor\: x = y \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: $\;\exists\;$ distributes over $\;\lor\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: x > y \rangle \:\lor\: \langle \exists y :: x = y \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: one-point rule"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: x > y \rangle \:\lor\: \textrm{true} \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify using $\;P \lor \text{true} \equiv \text{true}\;$"} \\
& \text{true} \\
\end{align}
Now we see that we didn't even use the fact that $\;\langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: x > y \rangle \rangle\;$ is false on $\;\mathbb N\;$...